# How to adjust the height of AngularJS Material Select Box?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I have the following code

```
<md-input-container style="margin-right: 10px;width: 13%;"  class="ScenarioDetailsDropdown" >
        <h4    class="LabelsPageOne">Geography Type</h4>

        <md-select ng-model="GeographyType" ng-change="SelectGeographyType()" >
          <md-option   ng-repeat="(index,ModelTableRow) in ModelTable | unique:'geographyType'" ng-value="ModelTableRow.geographyType" >{{ModelTableRow.geographyType}}</md-option>
        </md-select>

</md-input-container>
```

[image: Angular Material Dropdown]

How can i reduce the height of the Select Boxes?
Also, how can I reduce the top padding in md-input-container?
I tried using this :

```
<md-input-container style="margin-right: 10px;width: 13%;" class="ScenarioDetailsDropdown" style="padding : 0px 0px !important;margin:0px 0px;" >
```

But, its not working.
Can you please help me to do this??
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this the kind of thing you are after? [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/BzZpOJ)

[image]

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp" style="padding:100px">
  <md-input-container  class="ScenarioDetailsDropdown" >
    <h4 class="LabelsPageOne">Geography Type</h4>
    <md-select ng-model="GeographyType" ng-change="SelectGeographyType()" md-container-class="mySelect">
      <md-option   ng-repeat="(index,ModelTableRow) in ModelTable" ng-value="ModelTableRow.geographyType" >{{ModelTableRow.geographyType}}</md-option>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.ScenarioDetailsDropdown {
  margin: 0;
  background: green
}

.ScenarioDetailsDropdown h4 {
  margin: 0;
}

.ScenarioDetailsDropdown md-select {
  background: white;
}

.ScenarioDetailsDropdown md-select md-select-value {
  height: 20px;
  min-height: 20px;
}

.mySelect {
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Hi @camden_kid....Thanks a lot....I needed two things...1. reduce margin at the top , 2. reduce the height of the white select box....You have shown me how to reduce the margin at the top....So thats solves my question no. 1....Could you also show me how to reduce the height of the white select box?...Thank You!

Comment: @Sabyasachi See update. Specifically the CSS for `md-select-value`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom directive to support such a customization based on regular `<select></select>` elements. Unfortunately Angular Materials `md-select` element does not provide any related options.